# Facebook app doesn't show youtube embed video

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, youtube

I wanna view YouTube video randomly on my Facebook app but code show below and there is nothing

my code:

```
<?php
    $num=rand(0,2); 
    $video=array("Z0xfWCDLoCU","vv7EtBmZ-ko","Lh3TokLzzmw");
?>

<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Таны өнөөдрийн сонсох дуу</title>
</head>
<center>
  <body background="assets/1.jpg" >
</br>   
   <p style="font-size:30px"><?php echo $user_profile['name']; ?> Your song of the day </p>
</br>
</br>
   <p style="font-size:50px;color:#a7a7a7;"><?php echo $songs[$num]; ?> </p>

<?php echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$video[$num]\" frameborder=\"0\" ></iframe>"; ?>

  </body>
  </center>
</html>
```

and result is

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0k_1kvDh2UA" frameborder="0"></iframe>
       #document
         <html>
            <head></head>
            <body></body>
         </html>
        </iframe>
```

Comment: works fine for me. Just remove the `<?php` tag around your `echo`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran it has $video[$num] so can't be html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php

$num=rand(0,2); 
$video=array("Z0xfWCDLoCU","vv7EtBmZ-ko","Lh3TokLzzmw");

echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$video[$num]\" frameborder=\"0\" ></iframe>"; 
?>
```

The variables are declared otside the php...